# How to write SQL query to choose all suggestions someone has not given feedback on

Tags: sql

Note: I have massively simplified the data here for clarity, so please don't let the simplicity fool you into thinking the efficiency of this query is irrelevant.

Let's say I have a table of suggestions:

```
Suggestion
  id
  description
```

a table of contributors:

```
Contributor
  id
  name
```

and a linking table of feedback on the suggestions:

```
ContributorFeedback
  contributorid
  suggestionid
  feedback
```

The suggestions table may be very large and multiple contributors may feedback on the same suggestion.

What I want to do is write the most efficient query that shows me all the suggestions that a certain contributor has NOT given feedback for. It SHOULD include all other suggestions, whether or not any other contributors have offered feedback.

Essentially, this:

```
SELECT * FROM Suggestion 
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT suggestionid FROM ContributorFeedback 
  WHERE contributorid = 1234
)
```

Is there a better way using joins with the FKs in the database? It's been a hot while since I've done anything with SQL databases and to say I'm rusty would be an understatement.

Thanks.

Comment: *Is there a better way using joins* , yes it might be , using join or exist . For further detailed answer you need to post which dbms are you using, execution plan . Some data examples and expected result would be better to give a proper answer

Comment: There are almost always multiples ways of achieving the same result using SQL. Which one is better is almost always dependent on data volumes, indexing, etc. Therefore, for anyone to give you a useful answer you would need to run a working SQL statement against representative data volumes and provide the EXPLAIN PLAN

Answer (score 1):

Your query is the straight-forward way to write this, so I consider it the best query for the task.

You can do the same with `NOT EXISTS`. This would make the query just a tad less readable, but is preferred by many over `NOT IN`, because `NOT IN` does not work when there can be a null in the requested column (`ContributorFeedback.suggestionid` in your case).

Some young DBMS tend to have performance issues with `IN` clauses. That was true for early MySQL versions for instance. That is another reason why some people rather use `[NOT] EXISTS` or even anti joins in such dark times :-)

An aspect that can make a query efficient or inefficient is the existence of indexes. For your query, I see two main approaches:

1. Loop through all suggestions and check whether user 1234 made that suggestion.
2. Get all suggestions of user 1234 and then scan the suggestions and compare them with that data set.

For #1 you'd want this index:

```
create index idx1 on ContributorFeedback (suggestionid, contributorid);
```

For #2 you'd want this one:

```
create index idx2 on ContributorFeedback (contributorid, suggestionid);
```

You can provide both indexes and see which one gets used. Maybe the DBMS doesn't even see a benefit in using an index and uses neither. This probably depends much on the size of the tables. You can always drop an index again, when you notice it doesn't get used by the DBMS.